# tacacs server hostname problem

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, tacacs

When I am trying to configure tacacs hostname I have this message . I can't find solution for this problem.

```
Router(config)#tacacs-server host 192.168.20.1
Warning: The cli will be deprecated soon 'tacacs-server host 192.168.20.1' Please move to 'tacacs server <name>' CLI
```

Comment: one of the first links google returns http://slaptijack.com/networking/new-style-tacacs-configuration/

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's a warning that you are using an old, soon to be removed, configuration syntax, and gives you the new command.  There are plenty of guides on the subject; Ron pointed out one of them.